# stylus task compiles but not reload in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, watch, stylus

Recently, there is something going wrong with my project and i don't know where am i wrong? so need a fresh look and a help.

The issue is that when i run gulp my ***stylus task compiles fine*** (I see changes in css) **but it doesn't reload in chrome automatically**. I have chrome extension (livepage) and all nesessary plugins were installed locally with npm.

I tested another one which is most same and that works fine.

here is my gulpfile :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),  
    watch = require('gulp-watch');
//-  JADE
gulp.task('jade', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/jade/*.jade')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(jade({pretty:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});

//- CSS
gulp.task('css', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/stylus/*.styl')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
});

//- WATCH
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/stylus/*.styl', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('app/jade/*.jade', ['jade']);
});


//- DEFAULT
gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'css', 'watch']);
```

json :

```
{
  "name": "newone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5"
      }
    }
```

project tree

```
newone
  | app
    | jade
        index.jade
    | stylus
        style.styl
  | build
    | css
        style.css
    index.html
```

so, any advice? thank you...

Comment: You probably need another module for auto-reloading (live-reload), as gulp-watch just rebuilds. There is nothing in the devDependencies that allows for live-reloading. That's how I end up having to do it (though I use Brunch rather than Gulp).

Comment: well, i tried with live-reload but nothing change. others project works fine with (livepage) .that's  queerly

Comment: i've just clean my chrome and reinstall live-reload, now it works again. anyway, thanks for advice.

Comment: in general, the situation is strange. When I add to the project postcss ( csswring & autoprefixer) and run gulp i have in chrome outputs: 
**Could not connect to Live-Reload server. Please, make sure that a compatible Live-Reload server is running. We recommend quard-livereload, until Live-Reload comes to your platform.**

Comment: in my console I have this: 
`Container # eachAtRule is deprecated. Use Container # walkAtRule instead. Container # eachRule is deprecated. Use Container # walkRule instead. Container # eachDecl is deprecated. Use Container # walkDecl instead. Node # semicolon is deprecated. Use Node # raws. semicolon Node # after is deprecated. Use Node # raws.after Container # eachComment is deprecated. Use Cotainer # walkComments insteed. ....`
with all that gulp watches, compiles but no update in chrome...

Comment: You did read and follow the docs for that module, right? That module needs some to be setup in order to listen for changes. As for other projects working fine with livepage, you might want to look into what the differences are between those projects and this one. You might find your issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Browser-Sync for live reloading, it's awesome!

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var stylus      = require('gulp-stylus');

// Static Server + watching styl/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['stylus'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });

    gulp.watch("app/stylus/*.styl", ['stylus']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('stylus', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/stylus/*.styl")
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Good luck!